# Create trigger calculate total = quantity * price from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, database-trigger

I have two tables, `PRODUCT_tbl`, and `TRANSACTION_tbl`

```
PRODUCT_tbl
╔══════╦═══════════════╦════════════════╗
║ ID   ║ NAME          ║ PRICE          ║
╠══════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 53   ║ TEA           ║ 1000           ║ 
║ 29   ║ MILK          ║ 3000           ║ 

TRANSACTION_tbl
╔══════╦═══════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ ID   ║ PRODUCT_ID    ║ QUANTITY       ║ TOTAL          ║
╠══════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╣
```

How to create trigger that can multiplying `QUANTITY` based `PRICE` from `PRODUCT_tbl` table after insert on `TRANSACTION_tbl`

Example:

`INSERT INTO TRANSACTION_tbl (PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY) VALUES (53,5)`

```
╔══════╦═══════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ ID   ║ PRODUCT_ID    ║ QUANTITY       ║ TOTAL          ║
╠══════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 1    ║ 53            ║ 5              ║ 5000           ║
```

Comment: Hint:  Your trigger starts with `CREATE TRIGGER`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I would recommend against storing *derived* information, ie data that can be computed from other available values.

As an example, you could use a view for that:

```
create view v_ transaction as 
select t.id, t.product_id, t.quantity, p.price * t.quantity total
from transaction t
inner join product p on p.id = t.product_id
```

Comment: But I want to know how to create trigger not create a view
and sorry i had edit my question, cause TRANSACTION is a method in sql..